# Argument of type 'eventKey' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting this error while calling a TypeScript function in a React Project.

```
const handleLanguageChange = React.useCallback((eventKey: eventKey) => {
          setLanguage(eventKey);
          if(eventKey == "DE")
               setCurrency("€ EUR");
          else if(eventKey == "JP")
               setCurrency("¥ JPY");
          else if(eventKey == "US")
               setCurrency("$ USD");
          else
               setCurrency("£ GBP");
          const language = eventKey;
          changeLang(language);  >> ERROR HERE!
     }, []);

function changeLang(language: string) {
          i18n.changeLanguage(language, (err, t) => {
               if (err) {
                    localeChangeHandlerMetric.setFailure();
               } else {
                    localeChangeHandlerMetric.setSuccess();
               }
               localeChangeMetricsPublisher.publish(localeChangeHandlerMetric);
          });
     }
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
src/components/navigation/LanguageNav.tsx:44:22
TS2345: Argument of type 'eventKey' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    42 |                setCurrency("£ GBP");
    43 |           const language = eventKey;
  > 44 |           changeLang(language);
       |                      ^^^^^^^^
    45 |      }, []);
    46 | 
    47 |      function changeLang(language: string) {
```

Any idea how do I deal with this? I tried to add an optional type to the eventKey, but was not successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changeLang(language: string) receive language as type string. But you pass language as type eventKey. Some options you can do

**Option 1:**
Change type of eventKey

```
const handleLanguageChange = React.useCallback((eventKey: string) => {
          setLanguage(eventKey);
          if(eventKey == "DE")
               setCurrency("€ EUR");
          else if(eventKey == "JP")
               setCurrency("¥ JPY");
          else if(eventKey == "US")
               setCurrency("$ USD");
          else
               setCurrency("£ GBP");
          const language = eventKey;
          changeLang(language);  
     }, []);
```

**Option 2**: Type Assertion with "as" keyword

```
const handleLanguageChange = React.useCallback((eventKey: eventKey) => {
          setLanguage(eventKey);
          if(eventKey == "DE")
               setCurrency("€ EUR");
          else if(eventKey == "JP")
               setCurrency("¥ JPY");
          else if(eventKey == "US")
               setCurrency("$ USD");
          else
               setCurrency("£ GBP");
          const language = eventKey as unknown as string;
          changeLang(language); 
     }, []);
```

**Option 3:** Ignore it

```
const handleLanguageChange = React.useCallback((eventKey: eventKey) => {
          setLanguage(eventKey);
          if(eventKey == "DE")
               setCurrency("€ EUR");
          else if(eventKey == "JP")
               setCurrency("¥ JPY");
          else if(eventKey == "US")
               setCurrency("$ USD");
          else
               setCurrency("£ GBP");
          const language = eventKey;
          //@ts-ignore
          changeLang(language); 
     }, []);
```